# Coffee-Script Error in React App on importing external function(JS Google Api)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, coffeescript, google-api-js-client

I created a simple app by following this document [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

and it works great! 
Then i want to use google's api in js as you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js)

by importing "Option 1" script. I've tested it in a html file and it worked. So, i want to use that js script in my react app(for example calling 'start()' function onclick, i know how to do that). I tried: `import {start} from './apiCall'; 
                    var gapi = require('gapi');`

where apiCall is my js:

```
export function start() {
  // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
  gapi.client.init({
    'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    // Your API key will be automatically added to the Discovery Document URLs.
    'discoveryDocs': ['https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest'],
    // clientId and scope are optional if auth is not required.
    'clientId': 'YOUR_WEB_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'scope': 'profile',
  }).then(function() {
    // 3. Initialize and make the API request.
    return gapi.client.people.people.get({
      resourceName: 'people/me'
    });
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.result);
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
};
// 1. Load the JavaScript client library.
gapi.load('client', start);
```

At this point i get a lot of Coffee-Script errors:

```
Error in ./~/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js
Module not found: 'module' in C:\Users\Lavoro\Desktop\calendar_test_vm\vm_calendar\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script

Error in ./~/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js
Module not found: 'child_process' in C:\Users\Work\Desktop\calendar_test_vm\vm_calendar\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script

Error in ./~/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js
Module not found: 'module' in C:\Users\Work\Desktop\calendar_test_vm\vm_calendar\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script

Module not found: 'child_process' in C:\Users\Work\Desktop\calendar_test_vm\vm_calendar\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script

Error in ./~/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/grammar.js
Module not found: 'jison' in C:\Users\Work\Desktop\calendar_test_vm\vm_calendar\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script

Error in ./~/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl.js
Module not found: 'repl' in C:\Users\Work\Desktop\calendar_test_vm\vm_calendar\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script
```

How can i import an external function (in this case GAPI function) correctly?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Neither your code, the `create-react-app` repo you mention, nor the GAPI are using CoffeeScript. Why is CoffeeScript installed and what is calling it? What command are you using to run this app?

Maybe remove the coffeescript package from `node_modules` and try running it again.

Comment: It's the same, maybe it could be a "gapi" problem

Comment: gapi is using coffeeScript, I got this error immediately after installing gapi.
The index.js of the gapi npm package contains `require('coffee-script');
module.exports = require('./lib/gapi.coffee');`